# Creating multiple columns in pandas with lambda function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a set of new columns with growth rates within my `df` in a more efficient way than multiply imputing them one by one.

My `df` has +100 variables, but for simplicity, assume the following:

```py
consumption = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
wage = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
period = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
id = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

tup= list(zip(id , period, wage))

df = pd.DataFrame(tup,
                  columns=['id ', 'period', 'wage'])
```

With two variables I could simply do this:

```py
df['wage_chg']= df.sort_values(by=['id', 'period']).groupby(['id'])['wage'].apply(lambda x: (x/x.shift(4)-1)).fillna(0)

df['consumption_chg']= df.sort_values(by=['id', 'period']).groupby(['id'])['consumption'].apply(lambda x: (x/x.shift(4)-1)).fillna(0)
```

But maybe by using a `for` loop or something I could iterate over my column names creating new growth rate columns with the name `columnname_chg` as in the example above.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you could put your code in a for loop: ```for col in list(df):
    df[col + '_chg'] =df.sort_values(by=['id', 'period']).groupby(['id'])[col].apply(lambda x: (x/x.shift(4)-1)).fillna(0)``` This would create for all your columns a "_chg" column with the calculation you have above.  You could improve your code though. For example no need to run ```df.sort_values``` all the time, you can run it once before you do your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DataFrame operation rather than Series operation in `groupby.apply`

```py
cols = ['wage', 'columnname']

out = df.join(df.sort_values(by=['id', 'period'])
              .groupby(['id'])[cols]
              .apply(lambda g: (g/g.shift(4)-1)).fillna(0)
              .add_suffix('_chg'))
```